# How do you open Castin’ Craft resin cans?

Tags: tool-selection, casting

Ok. I have this can of Castin’ Craft brand polyester resin that is brand new. I unscrewed the top and was confronted with a second metal barrier:

[image]

I’ve tried:

- Prying it with a screwdriver.
- Grabbing the edge and unscrewing.
- Putting pressure from the inside and unscrewing.
- Stabbing it.
- Focusing my chakra, prana, and kundalini energy to visualize and create a portal through which I can pour out the contents.
- Yelling at it.

Before I just take a step bit to the top of this can, does anybody who’s used this resin know how to open this?

I know this might be a silly question but I’ve never had so much trouble opening a can before, and believe me I’ve opened a lot of cans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prying with a narrow screwdriver is a good start. It appears in the photo that you have a bit of a start at the near edge of the top.

This particular seal is a throw-away and you can indeed stab it. Something stronger than a pointed stick should do well enough. A small blade philips screwdriver tapped in then bent outward will distort the top sufficiently to pop it free.

Be not afraid, plunge onward!

Comment: Success! I couldn’t tell if it was discardable. I hammered a screw into it (‍♂️) and [pried it right out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luuww.jpg). Thanks, your mastery of cans is impressive indeed.